# Vaadin components is not editable when deployed from Linux

Tags: linux, vaadin

Vaadin components are not editable when deployed from Linux.
When deployed my application in Tomcat in Linux OS all the components of one page (other pages are working fine) is showing non-editable while same application when deployed on Windows doesn't have this issue.

Comment: Does "not editable" mean that components are disabled or set to read-only mode? Could this be caused by some system property or data source not being available in Linux deployment? Vaadin application itself will run in the same way regardless of operating system.

Comment: What component?

Comment: No sir. it is not disabled. As I, when deployed on Windows, doesn't have this issue. [Vaadin] (https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/16879976) you all can find the file in this link.

Comment: No sir. it is not disabled. As I, when deployed on Windows, doesn't have this issue. <a href="https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/16879976" title="Vaadin">Vaadin</a> you all can find the file in this link.